# How to select an element by it's text with Puppeteer and Headless Chrome

Tags: javascript

If I have a button that looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="list-group-item" style="cursor: pointer;">Button Text</button>
```

I'm trying to click it with:

```
await page.click(<button selector>)
```

I can't use the full selector I get if I copy selector from Chrome dev tools because the exact selector can change. Is there a way I can select a button based on what it's text is? For example:

```
await page.click('Button Text')
```

I'm also not using JQuery, so please keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery and maybe also a bit less overhead, you could use this:

```
window.find("Button Text", true, false, true) 
? [window.getSelection()].map(_ => _.anchorNode).map(_ => _.childNodes.length
  ? _.click()
  : _.parentElement.click()
) : undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's called XPATH. You just have to call [$x](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-pagexexpression) function like this:

```js
   await page.$x('//button[text()="Button Text"]')
```

Answer (score -2):

This maybe?

```
$('button').click(function(){ 
    if( $(this).text() === "Button Text" ){ 
        console.log("Do something here")
    }
 });
```

Comment: If you using plain javascript then grab all buttons and loop through them to find the text. Something like this: buttons[i].innerHTML === "Button Text"